# Пропадают данные из firestore после перезагрузки react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firestore

Данные выводятся нормально, но после обновления страницы пропадают. Хотя в массив записываются.

```
export const Product = () => {

 
  const [books, setbooks] = useState([])



  const addtodb = async()=>{
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "Products"));
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
    books.push(doc.data());
  });
}
addtodb()
  return (
    <>
    { (books.map((book)=>(
      <div key={book.id} className="product-cont">
      <div className="banana-container">
        <img src={book.productImg} alt="product-picture" className="banana" />
      </div>
      <div className="product-actions-container">
        <div className="product-info-container">
          <h1 className="product-price">{book.productPrice}</h1>
          <p className="product-name">{book.productName}</p>
        </div>
        <div className="btns-container">
          <button className="add-to-cart" >
            <img src={cart} alt="cart" className="add-to-cart-img" />
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div> 
    )))
    }
    </>
  )
}
``
```

Comment: Всё вновь появится если изменить что-то в коде

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению, не имею возможности ответить комментарием, на полноценный ответ это не тянет.

Честно говоря, с реактом не работал, работал с вью.
Возможно, я ошибаюсь, но хранилище состояния - не база данных, после перезагрузки страницы - весь ваш код приводится к дефолтному состоянию. Информация может хранится в LocalStorage например, или API сервере